# How to load Images in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Hey i am totally new in Codeigniter. In the Controllers folder I created a file named `caller.php` and I created a file `home1.php` in `\Views`. In `root directory` i created an image folder named `\Images` and also created a `css` folder named `\css`. In images Folder there are 6 picture. In css folder `style.css` file exist.

In `caller.php` i write

```
<?
class caller extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home1');

        // what i have to write here lo load images....

    }
}
```

In `home1.php` i write

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">

    // what i have to write here to load images


  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="outer">

      <div id="container">

        <div id="images">
          <img src="new.jpg" width="960" height="400"/>
          <img id="image1" src="1.jpg" />
          <img id="image2" src="2.jpg" />
          <img id="image3" src="3.jpg" />
          <img id="image4" src="4.jpg" />
          <img id="image5" src="5.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div id="slider">
          <a href="#image1">1</a>
          <a href="#image2">2</a>
          <a href="#image3">3</a>
          <a href="#image4">4</a>
          <a href="#image5">5</a>
        </div>
...................................................
....................................................
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now for the above code how i load the images .Please experts help me.
if additional config's are needed please mention that.

Comment: Just do the same as you did in case of css. Exact same. Only change the names and the html tag from link to img.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you're already using the url helper I suggest wrapping your image src attributes with base_url, such as:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/1.jpg'); ?>" />
```

And as mentioned in the other answer it's best (mandatory?) to capitalize the class name in your controller

```
class Caller extends CI_Controller { ...
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to capitalize your class name.

```
    class Caller extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            // method code goes here
        }

    }
```

Then, you need to link to those images with absolute links or with the CI URL helper: "/images/1.jpg" and so on. 
**How to use with the CI URL helper is detailed here** : [Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html)

EDIT

Load the URL helper with this in your constructor method:

```
    $this->load->helper('url');
```

You can create a URL like this:

```
    echo base_url("blog/post/123");
```

That will make:

```
    http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123
```

Or

```
    http://example.com/news/local/123
```

If you've taken out the index.php in your config file.

Here's a class with the constructor that calls the URL helper:

```
    class Caller extends CI_Controller { 

        public function __construct() 
        { 
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url'); 
        } 

        public function index() 
        { 
            // method code goes here 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Please post the answer here instead of linking it in order to avoid link rot.

Comment: If you explain it a little more then it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: In your controller, you need to add a constructor method to call the URL library. I edited the answer to show you.

Answer (score 1):

Make folder in root directory and code easily in views html file.

if directory name is directoryName and image name imageName.jpg

you can call like this.

```
<img src="directoryName/imageName.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same for as you did to Load the CSS files.
Create a folder in Root Directory. Create a sub folder(if you have Multisite)
then point your base_url in config file to your base path.

and then do the same
`<img id="image1" src="<?PHP echo base_url(); ?>images/[sub-folder]/1.jpg" />`

Comment: what do you mean by "point your base_url in config file to your base path". can you explain it a little more?

Comment: base_url to your path your root path. where you have application, system and other folders that you have created(Style, Scripts and Images).

Answer (score 0):

Only simple way

```
<img id="image1" src="<?php echo base_url('1.jpg'); ?>" />
```

That sit!!!