# How to retrieve image from folder in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my application, i have upload image and fill some fields. These values and upload image path also to be saved in database. I don't know to how to retrieve image from folder. My code is,

The Controller part is

```
function getdatatableajax()
 {

$this->load->library('datatables');
$this->datatables
->select("products.id as id, pathinfo, products.name as pname, price,   measurement, tax_rates.name")// measurement,tax_rates.name
->from("products")
->join('tax_rates', 'tax_rates.id=products.tax_rate', 'left')
->group_by('products.id')

->add_column("Actions", 
    "<center>
        <div class='btn-group'>
        <a class=\"tip btn btn-primary btn-xs\" title='".$this->lang->line("edit_product")."' href='index.php?module=products&amp;view=edit&amp;id=$1'>
        <i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i></a>
        <a class=\"tip btn btn-danger btn-xs\" title='".$this->lang->line("delete_product")."' href='index.php?module=products&amp;view=delete&amp;id=$1' onClick=\"return confirm('". $this->lang->line('alert_x_product') ."')\">
        <i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i></a>
        </div></center>", "id")

->unset_column('id');


echo $this->datatables->generate();

 }
```

The model part is

```
public function getAllProducts() 
{
    $q = $this->db->get('products');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

The View part is

```
<table id="fileData" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=10 class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("Image"); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("name"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("price"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("Measurement"); ?></th> 
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("tax_rate"); ?></th>
        <th style="width:45px;"><?php echo $this->lang->line("actions"); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty"><?php echo $this->lang->line('loading_data_from_server'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("Image"); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("name"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("price"); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("Measurement"); ?></th> 
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line("tax_rate"); ?></th>
        <th style="width:45px;"><?php echo $this->lang->line("actions"); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

From where are add image retrieval code.?

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/1.jpg'); ?>" />
```

[Check this Post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450608/how-to-load-images-in-codeigniter)

Comment: See my controller part, values from directly how can i add img src tag..?

Comment: Use This  <th><img src="<?php echo base_url('images/1.jpg'); ?>" /> </th>